# division by zero in a standalone program

Tags: assembly, divide-by-zero

We have a bootloader, and we have a program, the program is asserting 0 to register RAX. After that with DIV command, divides the register RAX by himself.

And of course bootloader loads the program.

I know any assembler give an error in this status, but the program is raw binary. So we can easily write this program with a hex editor because of the program consisting from only 2 instructions.

What happens in this status?

Comment: Maybe check the documentation of your CPU's vendor..

Comment: Intel Core i5 processor, and of course architecture x86_64

Comment: If you're going to do any serious x86(-64) development, get the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual_. The behavior of DIV is documented there.

Comment: No real answers yet.

Comment: Why do you expect *the assembler* to give a warning?

Comment: Assemblers are only programs for converting mnemonics to machine code. So you are right.

Comment: Typically, you either trap the interrupt that will be invoked, or test the divisor yourself.

Comment: Like [the manual says](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html), you get a `#DE` exception.

Answer (score -3):

According to book Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual:

The processor reports the divide-by-zero exception whenever an instruction attempts to divide a
finite non-zero operand by 0. The masked response for the divide-by-zero exception is to set the ZE flag and return
an infinity signed with the exclusive OR of the sign of the operands. If the divide-by-zero exception is not masked,
the ZE flag is set, a software exception handler is invoked, and the operands remain unaltered.

---

So, we have flag for that. When we try to do this, this flag will modified and value of the accumulator register will not chance.

Comment: That's what happens with when a floating point instruction divides by zero.   It doesn't apply to the DIV instruction.